# clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files error

Tags: c++, makefile

So I have the following files:

[image]

Then I have a makefile which contains the following:

```
CC = gcc

CFLAGS  = -g -Wall -std=c++11 -lstdc++
 
all: P0

P0: node.hpp tree.cpp tree.hpp main.cpp 
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) 
 
clean:
    rm P0 *.inorder *.postorder *.preorder
    rm -r *.dSYM
```

I'm getting the following error when attempting to compile all:

```
smajlovs@US3FHIM0XQ86TJG: ~/Personal/School/CMPSCI4280/project-0[main*]$ make
gcc -o P0 node.hpp tree.cpp tree.hpp main.cpp -g -Wall -std=c++11 -lstdc++ 
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
```

I'm looking at being able to run the following command at the end: `./P0 file`.

Comment: One thing is you should not pass header files to the compiler.  Source files (`.cpp`) are compiled.  Header files (`.hpp`) are included by source files.  However, this must be a quirk of clang because GCC allows this without complaint: you aren't trying to generate multiple output files.

Comment: Is there another way to rewrite this makefile to accept multiple output files? I can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong with the gcc compiler.

Comment: Just remove .hpp files from the sources for the target P0 as it is said earlier. Compiling a .hpp file produces a .pch file, thus the current command produces three outputs node.pch, tree.pch, a.out, and -o is able to change only one output name.

Comment: Sidenote: `CFLAGS` is the default for the C compiler flags. Use `CXXFLAGS` for flags to the C++ compiler. `CC` is the default for the C compiler itself. Use `CXX` for the C++ compiler. Also, since the question is a C++ question - use a C++ compiler, like `g++`, not `gcc` (which is supposed to be used as a C compiler).

Comment: @TedLyngmo, could you give me an example of a makefile for C++ specific if you don't mind?

Comment: @user17997251 Ok, I added an example.

Comment: Just to point out, you are _NOT_ using the GCC compiler.  Yes, I know you asked to use the GCC compiler.  But the output of your compiler makes clear that you're actually invoking clang, not GCC.  You are probably building on a MacOS system.  Apple plays all kinds of tricks on their system like shipping old versions of software and shipping "compatibility" features (that aren't actually compatible) like a `gcc` program that actually runs clang instead.

Answer (score 0):

> could you give me an example of a makefile for C++

This is an example how I'd start out with only the files I know exist in your project. This would be my *debug* or *development* `Makefile` since it uses a bit of static analysis and uses the *AddressSanitizer* and *UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer* libraries (which makes compiling and running the program a bit slower).

```
# The C++ compiler to use
CXX = clang++

# Runtime sanitizers
# Using AddressSanitizer and UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer will make
# the program a bit slower but helps when debugging.
SANITIZERS = -fsanitize=address,undefined

# $(CXX) options
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors -g $(SANITIZERS)

# Linking options
LDFLAGS = $(SANITIZERS)

# All your source files that needs to be compiled
SRC = main.cpp tree.cpp

# The object files you need from compiling the source files
OBJS = $(SRC:%.cpp=%.o)

# The final target
TARGET = P0

# clean target
CLEAN = $(TARGET) $(OBJS)

all: $(TARGET)

# linking - require all the object files
P0: $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
        rm -f $(CLEAN)
```

Example:

```
$ scan-build make -j
```

Comment: It's not useful to provide `-fsanitize=address,undefined` only at link time.  These options need to be provided at compile time as well.

Comment: @MadScientist Oups, how true. Updated, thanks!